# Grep-ing for lines in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, grep

I wanted to convert a Bash script to Python for training. The Bash script queries a remote host for its df via ssh and searches the returned line for a specific field, like so:

```
ssh $_host df 2>/dev/null | grep -i $_filesystem | grep :
```

In Python, I use `subprocess.call` in combination with `shlex.split` to get the "df" output:

```
_cmd = shlex.split("ssh %s df 2>/dev/null" % _host)
_test = subprocess.check_output(_cmd)
```

Here, _test returns as type **string** and if I want to search it line for line, it prints out every character as a new line. `subprocess.Popen` for pipes doesn't work either. All I want to do is print out the line in which my searchstring is found for further formatting.

I've already seen several attempts approaching a solution, but most of them iterate through files with defined carriage returns, not strings that are returned by a subprocess call.

Comment: Bash is a domain-specific language, designed specifically for interacting with processes. Python is a general-purpose language capable of doing anything. I'd like to see you write a webserver in a shell script.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, though it doesn't help at all.

Comment: The "proper" way to do it would be to import something that can handle `ssh`. I'd recommend `fabric` (google: "python fabric"). Currently you're just calling the ssh executable from python which is not how things are done (usually). Given your background in bash its understandable but unlike bash python prefers you to use **libraries**, not **executables**.

Comment: Thanks @ReutSharabani I'll try working with that, though I gotta admit, that I don't understand the fabric documentation at all. Also, I can't just install software from "unknown" sources on the live server I work on ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your narrative, the problem is that you iterate over the string `_test` (in code that you don't show). This iterates over one character at a time. So you just need to write

```
_test = _test.split("\n")
```

to turn `_test` into a list of lines, and you'll be getting lines instead of single characters when you iterate over it.

Comment: F me sideways, it was THAT simple? O_o
I've tried something similar, but with .strip(). I searched for "convert string to list" and even tried using a dictionary :D

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty simple thing :-) Python string handling is really powerful, read up on it. There's also `str.splitlines()`, which will treat consecutive newlines as one separator.

Comment: PS. Do heed the advice about not being so quick to launch subprocesses. In bash terms, a lot of the things you'd use a process for are "builtins" in Python (they have to be, for platform independence).

Comment: I'll try doing it as python as possible, but for some tasks, like ping or df, I found no easy or comprehendable alternative. Or I was looking for the wrong thing, that's also possible.
As for fabric, I don't understand anything of the documentation. x_x